# BigQuery ML unable to identify label column in data

Tags: google-bigquery

I am attempting to create a linear regression model with BQML, that uses a FLOAT column `trips_per_bike` as the model input

```
CREATE MODEL `bqml_tutorial.austin_bikeshare_model`
OPTIONS
  (model_type='linear_reg',
    input_label_cols=['trips_per_bike'])
```

The error message I get is "Unable to identify the label column in the data. Either specify the label column using OPTIONS(input_label_cols=['your_label_col']) or name the label column in the data as 'label'."

I am positive 'trips_per_bike' is a FLOAT column in the FROM table. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Not sure why MySQL is tagged here?

Comment: Can you post the full query? This one doesn't show what table you are using

Comment: most likely - you are missing that column (`trips_per_bike`) in the table you create model off of. please double check. otherwise  - provide more details

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Welp, I'm new to BQ and data analysis and didn't realize that `trips_per_bike` also needed to be included after my `SELECT` statement, I thought that was only for the columns I would use to measure the effect on `trips_per_bike`. After fixing this the model runs.

The error message seemed a little confusing because it lead me to believe that I was mislabeling the input column, which I did not have to change in order to make the model run.